# Kanban View Option

Tags: community

**Can we disable the option of Kanban view in salesforce, for particular profile Users ?**

That means if they open any list view they do not have an option to display record as Kanban view.

So  I think we don't have an option right now ? If anyone knows about this please suggest. Thank you.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdk1OUAR/ability-to-remove-kanban-view-option-for-users

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_networks_engage_modify_kanban.htm?_ga=2.73179153.346357526.1672035551-1544384467.1669026616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now we do not have any option to disable kanban view, however below is a simple CSS override to hide that kanban button on the list views.

```
button[title="Display as Table"] {display : none;}
```

Check details [here](https://nialljmurphy.medium.com/hide-kanban-option-on-list-views-in-salesforce-communities-660ae33471d8).